# How to access two same classes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have class called Configuration that is called in my controller.  Instead of instantiating my Configuration class, it is trying to instantiate a `ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration`.

How can I access *my* `Configuration` class, named the same as another library's `Configuration`?

```
class SampleController < ActionController::Base
  def m1
    cfg = Configuration.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SampleController < ActionController::Base
  def m1
    cfg = ::Configuration.new
  end
end
```

I'd recommend putting your own classes in their own modules, though.

In addition to avoiding class name collisions like this, it provides a structure from which you can hang more of your own code.